# Use jquery to fade background pictures without it going white in between

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this script to switch out background images in a single div and I would like for it to fade in and out; however, I don't want it to have any white in between. I have done a few searches; however, they all use list items instead of a single div. I would like for it to just transition from one background image to the next. Here is my current script:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {           
      var i =0; 
      var images = ['http://www.example.com/images/homepage/slider-2.jpg','http://www.example.com/images/homepage/slider-3.jpg','http://www.example.com/images/homepage/slider-1.jpg'];
      var image = $('#mainimage');
                    //Initial Background image setup
      image.css('background-image', 'url(http://www.example.com/images/homepage/slider-1.jpg)');
                    //Change image at regular intervals
      setInterval(function(){   
       image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
       image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
       image.fadeIn(1000);
       });
       if(i == images.length)
        i = 0;
      }, 5000);            
     });
</script>
```

Here is my current css:

```
    #mainimage {
      background: url('http://www.example.com/images/homepage/slider-1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      height:98.5%;
      min-height: 400px;
      border-bottom:15px solid #77951c;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="mainimage">
       <div id="searchwrapper"> 
        <div id="hometitlewrapper"> 
        <h1>Cabins & Cottages <span>for Sale</span></h1> 
       </div> 
       <div id="searchboxwrapper"> 
          <input id="state" class="autocomplete" type="search" placeholder="Search by Location" results /> 
      </div> 
  </div>
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/k4gh2ouj/)

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you tell us what your code currently does, not just what you want it to do.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to cross-fade the images. I've never done it using just one element, normally I have say two divs or images and fade one out to the other by making one transparent.

Comment: Oops sorry about that. It is currently transitioning from image to image. However, the problem is that the whole div including backgrounds, text and all elements go white for a few seconds. I need the elements within the div to stay constant and not fade to the white. I hope that makes sense, let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @Turnerj that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: show us your html also

Comment: <div id="mainimage">
         <div id="searchwrapper"> 
             <div id="hometitlewrapper">
              <h1>Cabins & Cottages <span>for Sale</span></h1>
             </div>
                <div id="searchboxwrapper"> 
                 <input id="state" class="autocomplete" type="search" placeholder="Search by Location" results />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: hey Chris, html and explanation should by added to the original post rather than comments to make the post useful reference later on

Comment: Whats your support levels? What is the purpose of only using one block level element? I can understand the semantic drawback of a `ul li` but using a few `div`'s would greatly simplify your life.

Comment: @darcher my reason for only having one block level element is because I was concerned about cross browser support and what you stated as far as the ul li options. I wasn't sure if I positioned divs upon divs if it would mess up with resizing. It would probably work in hindsight, but I like what your answer too much to change it now.

Comment: Makes sense. I updated the answer a bit to elaborate more on the "why" in addition to the "how" for future readers. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way of doing this, with only changing the one element, is by passing the transition off to the css layer. Use classes to adjust the background images.

Another benefit of updating the class instead of doing it all in the jquery/js is you can integrate user controls easier in the future if you want to incorporate start, stop, forward/back navigation at some point.

---

### Demo's

[CSS only image Preloading fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/k8r4886s/5/)

[JS image Preloading & Object Defer fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/k8r4886s/4/) -- Thanks Terry

*There are many ways to preload images & cycle classes, this is just a quick write up so do what makes sense for you*

---

### On to the code

**CSS**

I went with a cubic-bezier, basically an inverted `ease-in-out` for smoother transition but you can just as easily use `ease`, `linear`, or any other transition.

*add prefix's based on your support needs to both `transition` and `background-size`. Note that IE8 and below don't support `background-size:cover`, [read this article](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) for possible workarounds*

```
/* preload images (css only) -- remove if you're using a js method*/
body:after{
    display:none;
    content:url(http://placehold.it/400x400/4fa/222)
            url(http://placehold.it/500x500/fa4/222)
            url(http://placehold.it/600x600/4af/222)
            url(http://placehold.it/700x700/af4/222)}

/* background defaults*/
#mainimage{
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    transition:background-image 1s cubic-bezier(.44,.75,.38,.73)}

/* background image(s) */
.stage0{background-image:url(http://placehold.it/400x400/4fa/222)}
.stage1{background-image:url(http://placehold.it/500x500/fa4/222)}
.stage2{background-image:url(http://placehold.it/600x600/4af/222)}
.stage3{background-image:url(http://placehold.it/700x700/af4/222)}
```

**jQuery**

Then just update the class with the differing background images, with the desired interval... This can be done in literally any fashion you choose, I'm just updating the class with a simple count here.

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    $("#mainimage").prop("class", "stage" + counter);
    if (counter === 3){
        counter = 0;
    } else {
        counter++;
    }
}, 2000);
```

**HTML**

Add the base class to the `#mainimage` element, I recommend you use class instead of ID to alleviate any specificity issues.

```
<div id="mainimage" class="stage0">
    <div id="searchwrapper"> 
        <div id="hometitlewrapper"> 
            <h1>Cabins &amp; Cottages <span>for Sale</span></h1> 
        </div> 
        <div id="searchboxwrapper"> 
            <input id="state" class="autocomplete" type="search" placeholder="Search by Location" results /> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*...and, a pet peeve of mine, use `&amp;` for the "&"...*

Comment: Probably a good idea to preload the images, or at least run the setInterval function after all images have been preloaded to avoid flashing.

Comment: Totally agree with that.

Comment: Also made a fork of your fiddle: using jQuery `$.Deferred()` to check for image load ;) http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/k8r4886s/4/

Comment: Very nice, I just popped in a CSS preloading method. Thanks for the alternate method.

Comment: For Terry's option, I made a minor change where counter = 0 so that the first image shows. Thanks again! You guys are awesome!!